# in this object o= sc.ExecuteNonQuery(); is giving me error sqlexceptionunhandled what to do suggest me a correct code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SAGAR\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ClinicDb;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("insert into Patient_Details (Patient Id,Name,Age,Contact No,Address) VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "',);", con);
    object o= sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show(o +"Saved data");
    con .Close();
}
```

Comment: What is the detail of the exception? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Your column names have spaces in them which means you need to enclose them with braces e.g. `[column name]`

Comment: thank you sir it has work and yes i will use parameterized queries thank you

Comment: sir i am getting confuse with parameterized query can you will show me a syntax or code how would it return????

Answer (score 1):

fields and table names with spaces must be inside `[]`, also you have 1 extra comma in the end of your query. Try:

```
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("insert into [Patient_Details] ([Patient Id],Name,Age,[Contact No],Address) VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "');", con);
object o= sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

also consider using parameters, since you are open to sql injection.

Comment: thank you sir it has work and yes i will use parameters thank you

Comment: You don't need the `ToString`.  The `+` operator will automatically call `ToString` on `o`.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few things;

- `Patient Id` should be `[Patient Id]` and `Contact No` should be `[Contact No]` since they are more than one word. As a best practice, change their names to one word.
- You have extra `,` at the end of `textBox5.Text + "',` part.

But much more important, you should **always** use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

And use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections and commands automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connection))
using(var sc = con.CreateCommand())
{
    sc.CommandText = @"insert into Patient_Details ([Patient Id],Name,Age,[Contact No],Address) 
                       VALUES(@id, @name, @age, @no, @address)"; 
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox1.Text);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox2.Text);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", textBox3.Text);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no", textBox4.Text);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", textBox5.Text);

    con.Open();
    int i = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show(i + " Saved data");
}
```

By the way, I used `AddWithValue` in my example since you didn't tell us your column types but **you don't**. [This method *might* generate surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overloads to specify your parameter type (`SqlDbType`) and it's size.

Getting an `object` from `ExecuteNonQuery` is *really* strange as well. It will return `int` as an effected rows count. It will be `1` or `0` in your case.

As a last thing, I *strongly* suspect your `Patient Id`, `Age` and `Contact No` columns should be some numeric type, not character typed.

Comment: thank you sir it has work and yes i will use parameterized queries thank you

Comment: Please [don't recommend](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) to use `AddWithValue`

Comment: @DavidG I explained why I used it on the last part.

Comment: Hmm yes, but I'd rather just use example values than even hint at it's existence! :)